# Bulk Edit Sql Database - Remove Characters from Wordpress Image Captions

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, image

I'm working on a Wordpress project right now that involves hundreds of images. I've been uploading the images and setting the Captions and Alt text to the file names because I derped and thought the file name was a model number for each product.

It wasn't until after I uploaded about two hundred images that it dawned on me the LG in the image name stood for "Large Image" not a model number prefix. So now I need to go through and remove "LG" text from hundreds of alt text and caption fields.

Is there a sql command I can run to search all image captions and alt text for the characters LG and just remove those characters from captions and alt text?

For instance, a file name might be "LGWhite" so I set the caption and alt text to "LGWhite", when it should be just "White". How do I remove LG from everything in bulk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, 'LG', '')
WHERE your_field = XX
```

you may not even need the where?

Comment: I can find the images under wp_posts type="attachment" but there's no field for "caption". I'm a little lost right now. The captions seem to be hidden deeper than I expected.

Comment: HAHA! I got it. Apparently the "post_excerpt" is the caption. Awesome. Thanks man. Took me a little while to figure out since I'm not super familiar with SQL but that saved me a ton of time. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REPLACE(`column`, 'LG', '')
```

Comment: darn, i needed a new toaster

Comment: While this solution is correct, the other reply was a little easier for me to understand being less experienced with SQL. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With normal SQL-Statements its very likely that you'll damage your Installation, because nearly everything is saved serialized in Wordpress. 
If you edit the length, it expects an X-Character Caption but will find only X-2 Characters :-/

There is a wonderful piece of software, made for making changes to Wordpress databases:
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Hey, I installed that tool and it did make the changes, but it changed the image names too which broke all the links. I don't know how to specify to only change the caption. Do you know?

Comment: Hey, I was able to use the SQL command line without breaking the site. Thanks for the tool though. :)